# USB device access using Google Native Client (Nacl)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-plugin, google-nativeclient

I have a browser plugin which doesn't have visual interface and works in the background.The plugin is built using NPAPI technology.The browser plugin is used to Set Up USB device. Now we want to change it and use some other technology,since chrome is planing to move away from NPAPI.

I have gone through Google Native Client(Nacl) and PPAPI, it is good technology and  since it is Native Client means it allows the hardware access in my case USB devices.

I wanted to confirm my understanding on this.Please let me know whether Google Native Client supports USB device access from web.